# autofs error - “No such file or directory”

Tags: networking, mount, nfs, autofs

I am trying to link a remote RHEL machine to our network. I can now ssh between the machines using fixed NAT addresses. I have copied the `/etc/auto.misc`, `/etc/auto.master` and `/etc/exports` files from the local machine (called "cougar") to the remote machine (called "forth"), and restarted NFS and AUTOFS services on both. All ports are open on forth.

sample of auto_misc:

`forth_data        -soft   forth:/export/data`

sample of `/etc/exports` on "forth"

`/export/data       cougar(rw)`

Here's the command line error on cougar:

```
nm@cougar:/home/nm{119} cd /misc/forth_data
/misc/forth_data: No such file or directory.
nm@cougar:/home/nm{120}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

Before moving up to `autofs` make sure you can manually mount anything from the command line directly!

First see if you can see the exported shares from cougar:

```
$ showmount -e forth
```

If that works then try mounting them:

```
$ sudo mount forth:/export/data /mnt
```

If this works then you know 2 things which aren't causing you an issue.

1. The server is exporting the NFS share correctly
2. The firewall rules are allowing the connection

If you have any issue then work them out first with `mount`.

#### Areas of problems

1. Is nfsd running on forth?
2. Did you run `exportfs -a` on forth?
3. Is portmap running? (Needed for NFS v3, not for NFS v4)
4. Is rpcidmapd running? (Needed for NFS v4)
5. Is nfslock running?

There are more but this will get you started.

Comment: `showmount -e forth` on cougar returns `mount clntudp_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - RPC: Timed out` and `rpcinfo -p forth` states `rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: RPC: Remote system error - Connection refused`

Comment: I have checked steps 1-5 and all processes are running. I think it may be an external firewall issue. I have dropped the iptable firewall on both `forth` and `cougar` but the company also has a much wider network which our linux cluster is only a very small part of

Comment: @moadeep - yes if the above services are running then it's a firewall issue. You can run `strace mount ...` to see more information about where the mount command is timing out. You'll likely need to add some additional firewall rules for NFS. You can also check out this URL on how to run NFS over a firewall: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s2-nfs-nfs-firewall-config.html